# Choosing the frequency for a comb filter

Tags: matlab, fft, filters

I have an audio sample. From doing FFT on it it looks as if I need to use a comb filter to remove resonant frequencies. This is what I generate:

[image: FFT Image]

I honestly have no clue where to start unfortunately.

Comment: I'm not clear as to what you want your spectrum to look like.

Comment: Do you have access to the DSP System Toolbox in MATLAB?

Comment: Why do you want to remove the resonant frequencies. Doing so could severely distort the audio sample such that the audible quality is reduced. As Mikhail states, your question implies that you don't want your spectrum to look the way it does?